# CGI Perl Use of uninitialized value $user in string

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a problem checking if the variables I retrieve with CGI are right.

HTML:

```
<label for="name">Nombre de Usuario:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" />

<label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="user_password" />
```

CGI/Perl code:

```
my $c = CGI->new;
.
.
.
my $user = $c->param('user_name');
my $password = $c->param('user_password');

if($user eq "" || $password eq "") {
        printf "Error";
        exit;
}
```

The main problem is that if I just do:

```
print $user;
```

The output is correct and it prints the value, but in apache error.log, it still says that the variable is uninitialized and then goes into the "if" and exits.

I also tried with "$user" and comparing the strings to undef but nothing.

Comment: We would need to see what's between the declaration/initialization of `$user` and the reference (where you use it).  Is it possible it's in a different scope?

Comment: There is actually nothing between those two sentences

Answer (score 2):

To test whether a variable has a defined value, you should use the 'defined' function:

```
if (!defined($user) || !defined($password)) { ... }
```

Comment: This works, but I still have a problem with the variables, as they appear to be undefined, but I can access to their value.

Comment: That seems unlikely. You'd need to show a self-contained sample code that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score -1):

If those parameters have not been passed in by the form then they will be undefined, and you will receive a warning if enabled by "use warnings;".  You can ensure they are defined by providing fallback values for the assignments:

```
my $user = $c->param('user_name') // "";
my $password = $c->param('user_password') // "";
```